# prevent starting a new activity several times

Tags: android

I have a simple problem, In mu app the user has to click on a button to start a new activity, but if he clicks fast several times on the button the activty will be started several times. I have trued:

```
   holder.btnChoose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    synchronized (this) {
                        holder.btnChoose.setEnabled(false);
                        mListener.onChoose(item);
                        holder.btnChoose.setEnabled(true);
                    }

                }
            });
```

where in mListener.onChoose is

```
public void onChoose(boolean value)
{
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OfferSelectDatesActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
}
```

but this is not working. It seems that the startActivity(intent); works in a different thread and continues after the btnChoose, button is enabled.

Comment: You could put a synchronized boolean to true till it's not clicked and then pass it to false. You'd just have to analyzed if the boolean is clicked or not to start the intent.

Answer (score 1):

This might seem a bit kiddish,but works.
Create a global boolean in your class  : boolean alreadyClicked ;

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
              @Override
              public void onCLick(View v)
             {
                 if(!alreadyClicked)
                 {
                 startActivity(new Intent(this, OfferSelectDatesActivity.class));
                 alreadyClicked = true;
                 }
              }
        });
```

Then in the onResume( ) Activity call back set this  variable to false:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
        super.onResume();
         alreadyClicked = false;
    }
```

Comment: i think that it will work but i already went for the i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

Comment: this should work, thanks for the answer but ill try to find something more elegant, if not im choosing this solution for the best answer Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), YourActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(i);

Answer (score 0):

Just use a OnClickListener. This class calls only once the onClick method:

> ```
> button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
>       @Override
>       public void onCLick(View v){
>          startActivity(new Intent(this, OfferSelectDatesActivity.class));
>       }
> });
> ```

Comment: it is exactly what I do, my mListener.onChoose() is called in a OnClickListener

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in your **Androidmanifest.xml** for that activity which you don't want to launch multiple times.

Or do it programmatically as below:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), YourActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: He wants to prevent a double tap on a button to open two instances of the new activity. I guess you interpreted it wrongly, please edit your answer or delete this. Friendly Flag :)

Comment: actyaly this might not be the answer that im lookig for but for now it solves the problems so Ill vote one up

Comment: @Eu.Dr. where does the OP say that he/she wants to disable double-tap on a button? do you see it?  :)